# nu.studer.credentials does not work from inside Spock

Tags: gradle, groovy, spock, gradle-plugin

I am building a Gradle plugin that requires a username and password for the access to an external resource; to avoid clear text passwords, I use the plugin `nu.studer.credentials`.

To test my plugin, I use Spock; the following test file `CredentialsFunctionTest.groovy` was stripped down to only the relevant parts, to show the problem:

```
package my.gradle.plugin

import org.gradle.testkit.runner.GradleRunner
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.TempDir

/**
 * A simple functional test for the credentials acquisition.
 */
class CredentialsFunctionalTest extends Specification {
    @TempDir
    private File projectDir

    private getBuildFile() {
        new File( projectDir, "build.gradle" )
    }

    private getSettingsFile() {
        new File( projectDir, "settings.gradle" )
    }

    def "can run task"() {
        given:
//---> Begin of settings file <------------------------------------------------
        settingsFile << """
plugins {
    id  'nu.studer.credentials' version '3.0'
}

"""
//---> End of settings file <--------------------------------------------------

//---> Begin of build file <---------------------------------------------------
        buildFile << """
plugins {
    id  'nu.studer.credentials'
}

String username = credentials.forKey( 'myUser' )
System.out.printf( 'Username: %s%n', username )
String password = credentials.forKey( 'myPassword' )
System.out.printf( 'Password: %s%n', password )

task doSomething {
} 
"""
//---> End of build file <-----------------------------------------------------

        when:
        def runner = GradleRunner.create()
        runner.forwardOutput()
        runner.withPluginClasspath()
        runner.withArguments("doSomething" )
        runner.withProjectDir( projectDir )
        def result = runner.build()

        then:
        result.output.contains( "Alive!" )
    }
}
```

The output for "Username" and "Password" is `null` – that the test as such fails is expected, as there is no output for the String `"Alive!"` anywhere.

When I place the files `settings.gradle` and `build.gradle` (content below) to an empty folder, and call gradle with `gradle doSomething`, I get the expected output.

`settings.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id  'nu.studer.credentials' version '3.0'
}
```

`build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id  'nu.studer.credentials'
}

String username = credentials.forKey( 'myUser' )
System.out.printf( 'Username: %s%n', username )
String password = credentials.forKey( 'myPassword' )
System.out.printf( 'Password: %s%n', password )

task doSomething {
}
```

The `nu.studer.credentials` plugin stores the values in `$GRADLE_USER_HOME/gradle.encrypted.properties`, so one assumption is that Spock is using a different, temporary user and/or home folder.

Comment: Spock doesn't do anything in that regard, I'd suggest to look at `GradleRunner` more closely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the hint that [Leonard Brünings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2145769/leonard-br%C3%BCnings) gave me in his comment to my question, I was able to identify the problem and to create a solution.

As Leonard said, the issue is not with Spock as such, but with the `GradleRunner` that executes the test: this will use a different "Gradle user home directory" than a 'regular' Gradle execution.

With the parameter `-g` or `--gradle-user-home`, this can be changed, but it is not recommended to use this to point to the default location when testing a Gradle plugin (we are using Gradle to test Gradle here …).

Luckily, the `nu.studer.credentials` plugin provides an configuration parameter that allows to specify the location of the file that holds the encrypted credentials: `-PcredentialsLocation=<path>`.

So the solution looks like this (I took only the `when:` section from the original test script):

```
…
when:
def runner = GradleRunner.create()
runner.forwardOutput()
runner.withPluginClasspath()
runner.withArguments( "-PcredentialsLocation=%s/.gradle".formatted( System.getProperty( "user.home" ) ), "doSomething" )
runner.withProjectDir( projectDir )
def result = runner.build()
…
```

Of course, the test still fails, but it displays now correct values for `username` and `password`!